# Match Expression Results to Variable

Tags: php, regex, string

How do I match a pattern string with group of variables defined by `{{VARIABLE}}` from a string that contains the `{{VARIABLE}}` to an array?

**Example:**

I have the Pattern String:

```
$pattern = "Image_{{DATE}}.{{EXTENSION}}";
```

And I would like to pass the match string

```
$string = "Image_2016-05-26.png";
```

And after passing both strings to the function, return

```
$result = [
    "DATE": "2016-05-26",
    "EXTENSION": "png"
];
```

This includes, but not limited to the example variable:

```
$pattern = "Image_{{YEAR}}-{{MONTH}}-{{DAY}}.{{EXTENSION}}";
$string = "Image_2016-05-26.png";
// ------------------------------
$result = [
    "YEAR" => "2016",
    "MONTH" => "05",
    "DAY" => "26",
    "EXTENSION" => ".png"
];
```

(Optional, I think this is the hardest) But also only return values if they're found:

```
$pattern = "Image_{{DATE}}.{{EXTENSION}}";
$string = "Image_2016-05-26";
// ------------------------------
$result = [
    "DATE" => "2016-05-26",
];
```

Is there any way to build a function passing `pattern` and `string` as variables and achieve `result`?

Thanks!

Comment: By using real regexp patterns and named capture groups?

Comment: @mario I don't have such experience with regexp, I tried making it on regexr.com but no success.

Comment: So, share your attempts so far.

Comment: @mario No need for a regexp, use strtr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the overview of the steps you would need to do:

First, escape all of the characters which have special meaning to regex, except for the `{{` and the `}}`. Next, replace all instances of `{{` with `(?P<`.  Next, replace all instances of `}}` with `>.*?)`.  Then add the prefix of `/^` and the suffix of `$/` to the string.

That would convert the following pattern:

```
Image_{{DATE}}.{{EXTENSION}}
```

Into the following regex pattern:

```
/^Image_(?P<DATE>.*?)\.(?P<EXTENSION>.*?)$/
```

Now, use that regex pattern to search for a match.  Then loop through all the captured groups in the match and output the name/value pair for each one.

For instance, something like this will work for those examples:

```
function func_name($pattern, $string) {
    $pattern = "/^" . str_replace([".", "{{", "}}"], ["\.", "(?P<", ">.*?)"], $pattern) . "$/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $result);
    return array_filter($result, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```

Of course, all of this would be much easier if your input pattern was a proper regex pattern to begin with...

As far as making the extension variable optional, you can make a capturing group optional by adding a `?` after it, but there is no automated way of doing it according to your example because in your example, the `.` before the extension is also optional, but there is no indication in the input pattern that that is the case. In other words, you would need to convert it to `/^Image_(?P<DATE>.*?)(?:\.(?P<EXTENSION>.*?))?$/`, but there's no way of knowing, based only on that input pattern, that you would need to add the `(?: ... )?` optional group around the extension and the preceding period.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do your solution using that:

[pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/10853834/text)

But I got that:

`PHP Warning:  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found`

Comment: finally I got this: [pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/10853847/text), but do you think it could implement the part that ignores the not found values? At the `(Optional, I think this is the hardest) But also only return values if they're found:` part, it returns an empty array.

Comment: You can make a capturing group optional by adding a `?` after it, but there is no automated way of doing it according to your example because in your example, the `.` before the extension is also optional, but there is no indication in the input pattern that that is the case.  In other words, you would need to convert it to `/^Image_(?P<DATE>.*?)(?:\.(?P<EXTENSION>.*?))?$/`, but there's no way of knowing, based only on that input pattern, that you would need to add the `(?: ... )?` optional group around the extension and the preceding period.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Thanks.

Will you add the [answer](http://pastie.org/pastes/10853847/text) to your reply to mark as solution or should I create a solution?

Comment: Done.  I added the bit about the optional variable too.

Answer (score 0):

use php `strrt` function

```
function func_name ($pattern, $params) {
    $toReplace = [];
    $res = array_walk($params, function($v, $k) use (&$toReplace) {
        $toReplace['{{' . $k . '}}'] = $v;
    });
    return strtr($pattern, $toReplace);
}

$params = [
    "YEAR" => "2016",
    "MONTH" => "05",
    "DAY" => "26",
    "EXTENSION" => "png"
];

$pattern = "Image_{{YEAR}}-{{MONTH}}-{{DAY}}.{{EXTENSION}}";

echo func_name($pattern, $params); // Image_2016-05-26.png
```

Comment: This is wrong, the scheme should be
`func_name($pattern, $string)`
returns the `$result`;

Your solution returned `Image_{{2016}}-{{05}}-{{26}}.{{.png}}`.

Comment: You got it wrong. The objective of this function is read `$pattern` then for each variable formatted as `{{VARIABLE}}` return an array with the format `["VARIABLE" => "variable_value_in_$string"]`

Comment: @douglas ok! check now.

Comment: This is basically the reverse, check Steven Doggart's answer, and [my function of his answer](http://pastie.org/pastes/10853847/text), now the only part pending is the one I say `(Optional, I think this is the hardest) But also only return values if they're found:`